Get SQL Anywhere server version (NOT A DATABASE)
It looks like it is not possible to find what version of SQL Anywhere is running and to which I connected. Because it is everywhere listed as "Get the SQL Anywhere server version the DATABASE was made".
Not interested. I want to now the current running server version of SQL Anywhere.
Is it possible?
I tried sp_version and SELECT @@version, but the are for the big Sybase and not for SQL Anywhere and so produce an error as no such procedure/column.

To get the version of the SQLAnywhere software (not the version of the database file) there are a few options:
If you're logged into a database:
1> select @@version
2> go
 @@version                                                                                                                        
 ---------------
 17.0.9.4899

1> select property('ProductVersion')
2> go
 property('ProductVersion')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 ------------------------------ 
 17.0.9.4899

NOTE: if these generate an error then it may be a case of your SQLAnywhere software being extremely old or you're not actually connected to a SQLAnywhere database
From the command line, and assuming you have access to the dbsrv## binary, you can use the dbversion binary to display the version string of various SQLAnywhere binaries (eg, dbsrv##, dbeng##):
$ type -a dbversion dbsrv17
dbversion is /opt/sap/ASA17/bin/dbversion
dbsrv17 is /opt/sap/ASA17/bin/dbsrv17

$ dbversion /opt/sap/ASA17/bin/dbsrv17
SQL Anywhere Version Diagnostic Utility Version 17.0.9.4899
/opt/sap/ASA17/bin/dbsrv17: dbsrv17 GA 17 0 9 4899 linux 2018/11/07 21:52:49 posix 64 production
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^

NOTES:

re: the dbversion /opt/sap/ASA17/bin/dbsrv17 call ...
the 1st line of output is describing the dbversion binary
the 2nd line of output is providing the version details of the dbsrv17 binary with the version displayed as space delimited numbers (17 0 9 4899 in this case)

If your dbversion call gives you an error (eg, dbversion not found, or not able to find a .so file) then make sure your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables have been updated accordingly. In my case SQLAnywhere is used as a embedded component of another software package so I had to first issue the following:
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/sap/ASA17/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
$ PATH="/opt/sap/ASA17/bin:${PATH}"


If you're looking for the version of software the database file was created under (and last upgraded to) you can get a history of software versions from the SYSHISTORY view, eg:
1> select operation, version, last_time
2> from SYSHISTORY
3> order by last_time
4> go
 operation    version       last_time                          
 ------------ ------------- -------------------------------- 
 INIT         17.0.9.4899      Jul 29 2022 12:26:47.000000PM 
 LAST_BACKUP  17.0.9.4899      Jul 29 2022 12:26:51.000000PM 
 START        17.0.9.4899      May 12 2023 10:51:45.000000AM 
 START        17.0.9.4899      May  2 2024 10:54:08.000000AM 
 START        17.0.9.4899      May  2 2024 10:54:08.000000AM 
 LAST_START   17.0.9.4899      May  2 2024 10:54:08.000000AM 

If you're unable to log into the database you may be able to ascertain the version of the database file by running strings against the database file while looking for the version string next to a 'Copyright' message.  Keep in mind this may generate a lot of output.
$ strings db_name.db | grep -i copyright
... snip ...
Copyright (c)2015 17.0.9.4899 SAP SE, Copyright (c)2015 17.0.9.4899 SAP SE, Copyright ...
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
... snip ...

Since the SYSHISTORY data is in the db file another twist on the strings approach consists of running a grep for the various operations values, eg:
$ strings db_name.db | grep -E -A1 'START$|INIT$|BACKUP$'
START
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.15.0-105-generic #115~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mz&L
^^^^^^^^^^^
START
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.15.0-53-generic #59~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu
^^^^^^^^^^^
LAST_BACKUP
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon 
^^^^^^^^^^^
--
START
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon 
^^^^^^^^^^^
LAST_START
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.15.0-105-generic #115~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mz&L
^^^^^^^^^^^
INIT
17.0.9.48992Linux 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon 
^^^^^^^^^^^
--
CATALOGATSTART
CATALOGATSTART
select 1


I have the 17.x SQL Anywhere installed on my VM, so it is not outdated. I believe I am connecting to the DB and not just the server, but I will recheck on that.. I am actually on Windows {10} and trying to run it from the ISQL. Didn't try the second query yet. And as said in the question - the second portion of the answer IS IRRELEVANT..
